# Rotation matrix if X Y Z (The angles through which x y and z axis have been rotated ) are given.

Tags: rotations

If the x-axis is rotated by X degrees and y, z-axis by Y and Z degrees respectively,  then how to find the rotation matrix.
X Y Z are the angles by which each axis is rotated from the reference axis. For a single rotation of 45 degrees about z axis, X=45 Y=45 and Z=0.
I am trying to do this by using the basic mathematical definition of the rotation matrix.
\begin{bmatrix}x1.x0&x1.y0&x1.z0\\y1.x0&y1.y0&  y1.z0\\
z1.x0&z1.y0&z1.z0
         \end{bmatrix}

When I substitute the values fo dot products (unit vectors) I get
\begin{bmatrix}cos(X)&cos(90+Y)&cos(90-Z)\\cos(90-X)&cos(90)&  cos(90+Z)\\
cos(90+X)&cos(90-Y)&cos(Z)
         \end{bmatrix}

This matrix must reduce to the basic rotation matrix of z-axis when Z=0 is substituted, but it is not happening.  What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 4):

It should be clarified: matrix multiplication is **not** commutative, and so it is important to specify the **order** in which you want to perform rotations.

A counterclockwise rotation by $\theta$ about the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis are represented by the matrices:

$$ R_x(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta}\\
0 & \sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta}\\\end{bmatrix}\,,$$

$$ R_y(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos{\theta} & 0 & \sin{\theta}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
-\sin{\theta} & 0 & \cos{\theta}\\\end{bmatrix}\,,$$

$$ R_z(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos{\theta} & -\sin{\theta} & 0\\
\sin{\theta} & \cos{\theta} & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\,,$$

respectively.

Assuming you want the matrix representation $R$ of a counterclockwise rotation by $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ about the x-axis, y-axis and z-axis, respectively, then obtaining the matrix is trivial:

$$ R = R_z(Z) R_y(Y) R_x(X) = \ldots$$

Comment: X Y and Z is the rotation angle of each axis. X is the angle by which x-axis has been shifted not the angle of rotation about x. I just know the final values of X Y Z irrespective of how these values are achieved.